# Remote Debugger does not hit breakpoints in program running with Ant script

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, ant

I am using VSCode and Java. My goal is to get the debugger working since it is rather inconvenient not having it. Currently, my program is cleaned, built and run using an Apache Ant `build.xml` file. I was originally trying to use `launch.json` to run and debug the program, but I am having trouble getting past this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class FTEthernet
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FTEthernet
```

I switched to remote debugging by adding to my `build.xml`:

```
    <jvmarg value="-Xdebug" />
    <jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5432" />
```

And then setting my `launch.json` as:

```
{
  "type": "java",
  "name": "remote",
  "request": "attach",
  "hostName": "localhost",
  "port": 5432
}
```

This "worked" but it does not hit breakpoints, which leaves me at square one.
The code is executed from `cmd` and connects to an external mock software for the device the code will be used on. I am not sure what else I need to do to get this working. Client swears that it works for him, but when he showed me how he set his up, the explanation was "I just hit the debug button and it worked". So I'm at a total loss.

I have also tried eclipse, intellij, and running it from WSL and haven't been able to debug using any method.

Comment: If there's error in your code, the breakpoint won't be triggered but stop debugging then shown errors in Terminal. You should first solve the `Error: Could not find or load main class FTEthernet`. You may follow [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/606) and have a try. OR can you share the project for me to reproduce your question?